# How to write $pull update operation with condition in Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

My mongo query looks like this

```js
db.profiles.update( { _id: 1 }, { $pull: { votes: { $gte: 6 } } } )
```

**What will be the equivalent of this in Morphia?**

I see there is [removeAll](http://morphiaorg.github.io/morphia/2.0/guides/updating/) method but that doesn't seem to take a *condition* as argument.